# Probability of a candidate being selected for a job.

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

There are $8$ candidates applying for a job, and only $6$ of them will be selected. What is the probability of one specific candidate being selected?

Comment: You are likely to get better feedback if you include some *context* in your question.  Where did this problem come from?  Why do you care about it?  What have to done to attempt to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probability of an event is $\frac{\text{#Favorable Outcomes}}{\text{#Total Outcomes}}$

Here 6 people are getting a job, and there are 8 total people. So its just $\frac{6}{8} = .75$

Im guessing since you put combinations tags on it, they want you to use combinatorics. So you could also find the answer by solving for the total number of ways to choose 6 people from a pool of 8, which is $\binom{8}{6} = 28$, and the total number of ways a particular candidate could be in one of those 28 groups is $\binom{7}{5} = 21$ (since any of those 21 combinations you could just add him to it, and have a combination of 6 with him in it), so the answer is $\frac{21}{28} = .75$